# How to create groups in dataframes based on the values of multiple separaters in the data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
data = {
    'Name': ['AVY', 'SCOT', 'JYN', 'MAZ', 'SAS', 'LEN', 'PAUL'],
    'Value': ['A/A', 'A|G', 'GG|GG', 'G/GGGG', 'G|GG', 'AA/AA', 'TTT|TTT']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

df

```
    Name    Value
0   AVY     A/A
1   SCOT    A|G
2   JYN     GG|GG
3   MAZ     G/GGGG
4   SAS     G|GG
5   LEN     AA/AA
6   PAUL    TTT|TTT
```

I want to add a new column by splitting the df['Value'] by multiple separater. The separaters are `/` and `|`. If splitted values are equal group them into `G1` else `G2`. The expected output is as follows:

```
    Name    Value   Group
0   AVY     A/A      G1
1   SCOT    A|G      G2
2   JYN     GG|GG    G1
3   MAZ     G/GGGG   G2
4   SAS     G|GG     G2
5   LEN     AA/AA    G1
6   PAUL    TTT|TTT  G1
```

I tried:

```
df['Group'] = df.Value.apply(lambda col:'G1' if col.find('/')!=-1 else 'G2')
```

Comment: please post the method you wrote

Comment: I tried this but I have two separaters `/` and `|`. this code splits only `/`.

Comment: @svp.. added what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Splitting is pretty easy:

```
>>> split_val = df['Value'].str.split('[/|]', expand=True, n=1)
>>> split_val
     0     1
0    A     A
1    A     G
2   GG    GG
3    G  GGGG
4    G    GG
5   AA    AA
6  TTT   TTT
```

Then you only have to compare and assign groups:

```
>>> df['Group'] = (split_val[0] == split_val[1]).map({True: 'G1', False: 'G2'})
>>> df
   Name    Value Group
0   AVY      A/A    G1
1  SCOT      A|G    G2
2   JYN    GG|GG    G1
3   MAZ   G/GGGG    G2
4   SAS     G|GG    G2
5   LEN    AA/AA    G1
6  PAUL  TTT|TTT    G1
```

This last step can also be done with masking (.mask or .where):

```
>>> pd.Series('G2', index=df.index).mask(split_val[0] == split_val[1], 'G1')
0    G1
1    G2
2    G1
3    G2
4    G2
5    G1
6    G1
dtype: object
```

(This is the only answer that does not rely on slow `apply` or python iterating, so if you have lots of data it *should* be the most efficient, though I didn’t bother measuring it)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
df["Group"] = np.where(
    df["Value"].str.split(r"/|\|").apply(set).str.len() == 1, "G1", "G2"
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Name    Value Group
0   AVY      A/A    G1
1  SCOT      A|G    G2
2   JYN    GG|GG    G1
3   MAZ   G/GGGG    G2
4   SAS     G|GG    G2
5   LEN    AA/AA    G1
6  PAUL  TTT|TTT    G1
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try list comprehension:

```
df['Group']=['G1' if x==y else 'G2' for x,y in df['Value'].str.split(r'[|/]',n=1)]
```

Comment: This will probably throw an error if a row is unexpectedly missing a separator

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`nunique()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) on `axis=1` to get the number of unqiue values after splitting, as follows:

```
df['Group'] = np.where(df['Value'].str.split(r'/|\|', expand=True).nunique(axis=1).eq(1), 'G1', 'G2')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df)

   Name    Value Group
0   AVY      A/A    G1
1  SCOT      A|G    G2
2   JYN    GG|GG    G1
3   MAZ   G/GGGG    G2
4   SAS     G|GG    G2
5   LEN    AA/AA    G1
6  PAUL  TTT|TTT    G1
```